# How to perform a NSUser settings (which can be done in MAC development) in wpf using c#

Tags: wpf

I am a come from actually a Mac development background so I'm not that familiar with c# or wpf.

I want to do In programmatically way so, you can explain step too.

1) What would be the equivalent of User Settings in c#?

2) How to perform a store of one key and whenever want to retrieve its value, i just want to ask like       Value For Key?

```
For example in MAC i do like :

User_Defaults *prefs;
store different value in prefs.

and then i want this: [prefs value_For_Key:Key_Name] and get its value.
```

3)How to do this using c# in windows programming foundation?

SO, help me if anyone have a any idea?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this thing can be possible in two ways in wpf using c#:
1) I need to create one class in which provide getter and setter method for the key value
and access this class to get the value of the key. but it will increase manual work if i would update the key later on 
2) Store the key in database and get its value by accessing database.

Any one have any other idea then help me out.